# Jenkins Converts linux bash script when deploying to AWS Codedploy

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am using Jenkins to build a project from Bitbucket and as a post build option I am deploying to an AWS EC2 instance using the CodeDeploy plugin. I have a bash script in my workspace on Jenkins that is a unix bash script meaning the line endings are /n obviously. The problem is when I go to run the bash script on the AWS instance after is it is deployed I am unable to run it because it somehow was converted to windows endline chars (/r/n). It is not option to just convert manually on the AWS instance as I am trying to automate a testing environment. I am not sure how this is possible. Does anyone have any ideas on how or why this maybe happening or how to fix it? Thank you in advance.